# How to use System.Diagnostics.TraceSource instead of System.Diagnostics.Debug class?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, conditional-compilation, system.diagnostics

I am reading the [.NET Framework Development Guide - How to: Use TraceSource and Filters with Trace Listeners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993(v=vs.110).aspx) and right at the beginning there is the following recommendation:

> A primary difference for version 2.0 is that traces can be initiated through instances of the [TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx) class. [TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx) is intended to function as an enhanced tracing system and can be used in place of the static methods of the older [Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx) tracing classes. ***The familiar [Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx) classes still exist, but the recommended practice is to use the [TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx) class for tracing.***

I understand how [TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx) is used instead of [Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but I haven't yet understood how it is used to replace [Debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is a quote from a book [C# 5.0 in a Nutshell: The Definitive Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449320104):

> ***Debug*** and ***Trace*** are static classes that provide basic logging and
>   assertion capabilities.
>   The two classes are very similar; ***the main***
>   ***differentiator is their intended use***.

Now, here is a more in-depth description of the difference:

> All methods of the Debug class are defined with **[Conditional("DEBUG")]**.
>   All methods of the Trace class are defined with **[Conditional("TRACE")]**.

So, it leads to elimination of [Debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx) calls in Realease build:

> This means that all calls that you make to [Debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) are eliminated by the
>   compiler unless you define **DEBUG** or **TRACE** symbols.

How does [TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx) account for that difference?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, `TraceSource` doesn't record `Trace.XXX` or `Debug.XXX` calls, only `TraceSource.XXXX` calls. It doesn't have to account for that difference, since it doesn't listen to those calls anyway... You are welcome to look at the `TraceSource` code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/TraceSource.cs but the `TRACE` still needs to be defined to record calls.

Comment: @Ron: Sorry for me being not clear enough :)
How would you replace `Debug.WriteLine()` with the calls to `TraceSource traceSource;`, so that they would also be stripped from **DEBUG** build?

Comment: @Ron: I have looked at the source code `TraceSource.cs` and I haven't found any method marked **[Conditional("DEBUG")]**. It is really possible that I am missing something, could you, please, point me at that method?

Comment: They are marked `[Conditional("TRACE")]`, so the trace will still work in release as long as the `TRACE` symbol is defined. If you want them stripped from the **debug** build, then go into the Build properties and uncheck the "Define TRACE constant` checkbox for the debug build settings. DEBUG doesn't imply TRACE.

Comment: BTW, `TRACE` is also by default defined for release builds, and you change it the same way. You can also undefine it for a single code file by including `#undef TRACE` at the top of the file.

Comment: @Ron: Please, forgive me again for my lack of clarity.  
I don't want to strip methods marked as `[Conditional("TRACE")]`, I want old statements `Debug.WriteLine()` to transform into `traceSource.WriteDebug()` and I want these `TraceSource` calls to be stripped from DEBUG build.

Comment: You want to do it automatically? Like calls to `Debug.WriteLine` are re-routed to the tracesource? The latter part is simple, just uncheck the trace definition from the debug build. But how are you wanting to "transform" the old statements? I can give an example on how to do this automatically if needed...

Comment: use EventSource instead: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/07/09/logging-your-own-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981: Why?

Comment: you can correlate your events to System events (CPU, disk, network calls) to see how your code impacts the system.

Comment: @magicandre1981: wow, that is too powerfull for my application :)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I came up with is writing extention methods. If there is anything better out there, I will mark your answer as accepted :).

```cs
public static class TraceSourceExtentions
{
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void TraceDebug(this TraceSource traceSource, string message)
    {
        traceSource.TraceEvent(
            eventType: TraceEventType.Verbose,
            id: 0,
            format: message);
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void TraceDebug(this TraceSource traceSource, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        traceSource.TraceEvent(
            eventType: TraceEventType.Verbose,
            id: 0,
            format: format,
            args: args);
    }
}
```

This solution doesn't satisfy me, because, if there are multiple assemblies that need debug traces, we are doomed to consider either *code duplication* across these assemblies or creating an external redundant dependency (another assembly which will contain this class).